# Entity with Nestjs

Tags: javascript, nestjs

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the StoryController, but problem in this constructor

I really don't unserstand where my error

In this part code Error (why I don't understand)
more details: all work without

```
 constructor(
    @InjectRepository(StoryEvent)

    private readonly storyRepository: Repository<StoryEvent>,
  ) {}
```

*story.event.ts*

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class StoryEvent {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  title: string;
  @Column()
  text: string;
  @Column()
  author: string;
  @Column()
  date: string;
}
```

*story.controller.ts*

```
import { Controller, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { StoryEvent } from './story.event';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Controller('/story')
export class StoryController {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(StoryEvent)
    private readonly storyRepository: Repository<StoryEvent>,
  ) {}

  @Get(':id')
  getStory(@Param() params: number) {
    return params;
  }
}
```

all okay

*app.module.ts*

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { StoryEvent } from './story/story.event';
import { StoryController } from './story/story.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: 'EXAMPLE',
      database: 'postgres',
      entities: [StoryEvent],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, StoryController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Upd:
log in console:

```
[Nest] 3052  - 04.07.2023, 22:28:15     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 3052  - 04.07.2023, 22:28:15     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +53ms
[Nest] 3052  - 04.07.2023, 22:28:15   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the StoryContro
ller (?). Please make sure that the argument StoryEventRepository at index [0] is available in the AppModule cont
ext.

Potential solutions:
- Is AppModule a valid NestJS module?
- If StoryEventRepository is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If StoryEventRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing StoryEventRepository */ ]
  })
```

p.s. Thank u so much

code without error, see docs

Comment: Do you have a `StoreModule`? What is the exact error?

Comment: [Nest] 3052  - 04.07.2023, 22:28:15   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the StoryContro
ller (?). Please make sure that the argument StoryEventRepository at index [0] is available in the AppModule cont
ext.

Comment: No need to add large code blocks to comments. Just edit your question to add the extra information

Comment: @Jay McDoniel, I don't have StoreModule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so if you don't have a `StoryModule` what you need to do is add `TypeormModule.forFeature([StoryEvent])` into the `imports` of your`AppModule` *along with* the `TypeormModule.forRoot()`. This creates the injection token Nest needs to know how to map the `@InjectRepository(StoryEvent)`